# Sum of values from two rows of a table into a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, view

I have a SQL table which mentions stock quantity like this:

Tool:              Stock 
A:                 100 
A:                 200 
B:                 50

I want to create a view where it will give me the following output, where it would count the sum of same tool numbers:

Tool:              Stock 
A:                300 
B:                50

How to achieve this?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  `SUM()`. What have you tried?

Comment: Here are the resources to create view `https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp`, group by and sum `https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below -

```
create view view_name as
    select tool, sum(stock)
    from tablename
    group by tool
```